# Немогу получить значения из ajax запроса

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

У меня не проходят значения из if, значения которое я получаю, ето 4

```
public function department_view(Request $request, $city, $id) {

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $employees = Employee::get();
            $employee_id = 0;
            $employees_ready = 10;
            foreach ($employees as $employee) {

                $orders = Order::where('city_id', $request->cityID)->where('department_id', $request->depID)->where('date', $request->date)->where('employee_id', $employee)->get();
                $employees_ready = 4;
                foreach ($orders as $order) {
                    $employees_ready = 3;
                    if ($request->timeStart > $order->start_minutes && $request->timeStart < $order->end_minutes) {
                        $employees_ready = 1;
                    }
                    if ($request->timeEnd > $order->start_minutes && $request->timeEnd < $order->end_minutes) {
                        $employees_ready = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        $employees_ready = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                $employee_id++;
            }

            return $employees_ready;
        };

        return view('view', ['data' => Departments::where('id', $id)->get(), 'city' => $city]);
    }
```

Comment: то есть просто так вы из экшена решили вернуть целое число и это нормально для фреймворка будет?

Comment: А как правильно зделать?

Comment: Я бы сделал отдельный метод... А по поводу вопроса - надо проверить запрос. `$request->ajax()` проверяет чтобы заголовок запроса содержал `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`